# Select MF of the contact smart card

Tags: smartcard

I tried to select master file MF from contact card using APDU commands according to the ISO7816-4 instructions

as follow:

1. Initialized reader
2. Connect to the Card
3. Select MF  -> [00 A4 00 00 02 00 3F]    result [69 85] (Condition of use not satisfied)

I think it there is a missing step before the selection command, please your advise

Comment: Does `[00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00]` work (as masterfile usually has file identifier  `0x3F00`)?

Comment: no its not working, return with error 6985, I need sample code to write /read binary data to/from  smart card.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for that smartcard? There are many different smartcard types (and some of them do not conform to ISO 7816-4). Which one exactly are you using?

Comment: it's SCOSTA smart card

Answer (score 1):

Let check selection method from ATR to ensure that your card accept SELECT command by name, by identifier or by path...
You can check in ISO 7816-4, or you can also check here by copying your ATR to the input box: https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/

Comment: ATR = 3B 67 00 00 01 04 01 01 13 0C 01

Comment: Ahm.. I guess that your card is a Java card, so, you can't select MF directly through your APDU, in Javacard, you have to write applet and install it to the card, the applet which is the bridge will receive your APDU and send it to the card. I'm fairly sure because I struggled with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most smartcards these days are JavaCards; that is, they are programmable in a Java dialect, and capable of running different on-card programms / applications, also called "cardlets".

Sometimes, one of these cardlets is selected by default; but often, that's not the case.
Looks to me like you're expecting the former and getting the latter.

So, first, you have select the cardlet you want to talk to.

Example: You expect the "IsoApplet" to be available, which implements a PKCS15 structure in which you can start with MF and then look into the directories as you probably expect.

Select it after reset by sending `00 A4 04 00 0C F2 76 A2 88 BC FB A6 9D 34 F3 10 01`;

When that is successful (`90 00`), then you can proceed with your "SELECT MF" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If it is SCOSTA card, send "00A4000C 02 3F00" to select MF
i.e. Command APDU: CLA=0x00 INS=0xA4 P1=0x00 P2=0x0C Lc=0x02 DATA(hex) = 3F 00 Le=(EMPTY)